# Meteor - Iron router: redirect on invalid parameter

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have the following route:

```js
Router.route('publication/:_id', {
    name: 'show_publication',
    controller: 'PublicationController',
    action: 'show',
    where: 'client',
    waitOn: function() {

        return [
            Meteor.subscribe("publication", new Mongo.ObjectID(this.params._id)),
            Meteor.subscribe("deal", new Mongo.ObjectID(this.params._id))
        ];
    }
});
```

And the following controller action:

```js
// ...
show: function() {

    var publication = Publications.findOne({
            _id: new Mongo.ObjectID(this.params._id)
        });


    if (publication) {
        this.render('Publication', {
            data: publication
        });

    //The hex string is valid but it's not a publication _id
    } else {
        Router.go('home');
    }

}
// ...
```

The `_id` parameter is an hex string and with that I create an `ObjectID` to retrive a publication.

The problem comes when the parameter is not a correct hex string. I get this error in the console:

```
Exception in callback of async function: Error: Invalid hexadecimal string for creating an ObjectID
```

So, before calling the `waitOn` function I would  like to check if the hex string is valid and, if it is not, redirect to the home page. I tried to use `onBeforeAction`:

```js
// ...
onBeforeAction: function() {

    try {
        new Mongo.ObjectID(this.params._id);
    } catch (e) {
        Router.go('home');
    }
}
// ...
```

But it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
onBeforeAction: function() {
      try {
        new Mongo.ObjectID(this.params._id);
      } catch (e) {
        Router.go('home');
      }
    }
```

instead of "onBeforeAction:" write the above code in "data:" callback, as your waitOn function waits till data returned

```
data: function() {
      try {
        new Mongo.ObjectID(this.params._id);
      } catch (e) {
        Router.go('home');
      }
    }
```